# Open Graph not working for status updates for blog posts

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Status updates with a link to a blog that I help support aren't including the preview with the image, and description. It looks like the meta tags are included in the source. I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

Here is an example of what we are trying to share: `http://www.thetroubadoursroad.com/featured-artist-matthew-and-the-atlas-i-will-remain/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the errors which are shown on the debugging page: [Facebook URL linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.thetroubadoursroad.com/featured-artist-matthew-and-the-atlas-i-will-remain/).

For example, the `og:url` meta is present two times in the source of your page. You need to remove one of them (maybe you have installed two plugins which both add the `og:` metas?)

You'll also need to set an `fb:app_id` (register your application [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and you'll get one).

Comment: Yes, I've been playing around with different plugins.  I'll remove one of them now.  It is still an issue with one.

Comment: I checked the facebook debugging, and i'm not sure why it can't see the og properties.

Comment: i added the app id to the plugin for wordpress that i created.  it still doesn't look like it is working... any additional thoughts?

Comment: Its working now. After you make changes to the og-metas always open the link in the facebook lint tool otherwise information from cache will be shown when the url has been posted to facebook before. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped.